# Why does component remounted every time it recieves different keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does component remounted every time it receives a different key from props?

Every time when a different value passed to key props it remounted component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Box from "./box";

const randomNumber = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
};

function App() {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setKey(randomNumber());
        }}
      >
        update key
      </button>
      <h5>key: {key}</h5>
      <Box key={key} id={key} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-thompson-rw458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `key` is expected to be a stable identifier for the node. By changing it you're telling React that the node is new. This is the same as replacing it entirely with another type.

If this still isn't clear you may want to [review the documentation demonstrating their use](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) or read more about [why they are necessary inside of lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children).

Notably, your example is using a `key` where it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I see coreyward already provided the answer for you. I forked the sandbox for you so you can see that if you don't change the key attribute on the Box everytime the Box component will not mount and unmount anymore everytime the number changes.

I would also advise not to name the value you randomly calculate 'key', since this can be confusing with the use of the key attribute that shouldn't be changed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dijkstra-d5s5e

```
<Box id={key} />
```

instead of

```
<Box key={key} id={key} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a [reserved property name](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html). React uses `key` differently from other properties; in particular, React will remount a component whose `key` property has changed.